# Is it advisable to "wrapped" my tokens in order to use inside my Dapp to lessen gas cost?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, blockchain, gas, wrapped-tokens

I created a token ABC and have another smart contract for my dapp.

My Dapp requires a lot of ABC token burning for every tx, my question is, is it advisable to convert my ABC token from on-chain to my server, somehow like "wrapped" concept, but not blockchain to blockchain but blockchain to my server, to lessen the gas cost?

so does the user will not use the blockchain for every tx (together with burning), and if the user wants to withdraw, he can convert it back to the blockchain (unwrapped).

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Upto what I understand, you want that user's transaction would not be broadcasted to blockchain and would happen just in the server. This could be implemented but this would not make your app decentralised.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Abhijay! 

Yup. some of the transactions but not all (preferably the txs with burning since they occupy a large number of txs, which the user will cost gas)

what I want is to burn it off-chain but the user can convert it back eventually thru minting (if he/she wants to withdraw the token eventually).

Comment: Burning off tokens would require transaction to blockchain as you are changing the supply of your coin. you could set a function where you would first calculate the number of tokens that should be burned in 7 days or so and burn all of them in one transaction, and in your server side, you decrease supply of the coin whenever user burns it and increase supply when user mints, in other words, maintain another total supply thing on server side